# Why ArgoCD recycle all resources if only Deployment label is changed

Tags: argocd

I am currently using ArgoCD as part of our application deployment.  Our application is using the following `syncPolicy`:

```
    automated:
      prune: true
      selfHeal: true
      allowEmpty: false
    syncOptions:
      - Validate=false
      - PrunePropagationPolicy=foreground
      - PruneLast=true
    retry:
      limit: 1
      backoff:
        duration: 5s
        factor: 2
        maxDuration: 3m
```

When we deploy our application, we have the following `Kind`, namely `Deployment`, `Service`, `Ingress`, `ConfigMap`, `Secret`....etc.  For certain occasion, when we update our `ConfigMap`, we would like to automate to roll our pods.  Instead of using thirdparty controller like `reloader` or `kustomize config hash`, we just manually generate a hash in our Deployment template spec like below:-

```
    metadata:
      annotations:
        app.dev/configmapHash: md5-092ba50b1
```

This serve our purpose, but ArgoCD somehow see this changes and went ahead mark all resources OutOfSync even other resources has no changes.  ArgoCD then recycle all other resources include `Ingress` which causes alb controller keeps changing.  We couldn't find out when changing a `label`/`annotation` at the template spec level will cause all resources to be recycle.  We would expect only the pod/replicaset to do so.  When we apply the resources manually using `kubectl`, it seems working as expected where only `Replicaset` / `Pod` is being recycle, other resources remain intact.  Is there something wrong or I need to configure in ArgoCD in order to achieve this ?  When label/annotations change in `template.metadata` spec, we do not want other resources to recycle because there is no changes to those resources.

ArgoCD version : `v2.2.5+8f981cc`

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out where the issue was.  It was due to we reapply the argocd application yaml file every time we deploy, this triggers every single resources to be recycled.